# SQL SUM function inquiry

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a hard time summing up a column on two tables.  The scenario is something like this (refer to the image below)

[image]

Table 1 may have a lot of rows per Date.  But Table 2 may only consists of two rows of data per Date.  What I wanted to do is to sum up all Item/Price (Table1) according to their Date and ADD them with another SUM of Item/Price of Table2.  The category of SUM is by Date.

I tried any joins statement (left, right or inner) but it does not produce the result that I am expecting to.  My expected result is the Result table.  But on my query, it produces a very high value.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify in your question that items in table 1 and table 2 are not really related. The sample data is misleading due to the same names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UNION` clause like this:

```
WITH t(d, p) AS (
    SELECT [Date], Price FROM Table1
        UNION ALL
    SELECT [Date], Price FROM Table2
)
SELECT d, SUM(p) FROM t GROUP BY d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `UNION  ALL` in either a subquery or a cte, cte shown here:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT [Date], Price 
              FROM Table1
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT [Date], Price 
              FROM Table2
             ) 
SELECT [Date], SUM(Price) AS Total_Price
FROM cte
GROUP BY [Date]
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c2ace/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
with cte (C_Date,C_Price)
as
(
SELECT date,SUM(price) FROM table_1
group by date
union 
SELECT date,SUM(price) FROM table_2
group by date
)
select c_date,SUM(c_price) from cte
group by C_Date
```

Comment: If the two tables generated the same `SUM()` for a given date, this would fail, as `UNION` removes duplicate values, need `UNION  All`.  Also probably more efficient to not bother with the aggregation in the cte.

Comment: Yes, it works with the example values, but if the values in each table have the same `SUM()` it will produce incorrect total.  
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07008/1/0

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Select t.date,P1+P2
from(
Select Date,sum(Price) P1
from table1 t
group by Date
) t
left join 
(
Select Date,sum(Price) P2
from table t2
group by date
) t1 on t.date = t1.date
group by date
```